# PHP - Infinite looping while scandir() and checking count

Tags: php

I am creating a online application in PHP and as part of this I need to have a function where I give it a directory and it will count all the files in that folder, all the folders in that folder, and all the folders in the sub-directories etc until all files and sub-files in that folder are counted.

I have tried multiple methods and from doing my own research most people do it the way I have tried to attempt it but I am getting no success with my method.

**Here is the code i currently use:** (The $uniqueKey parameter is not the issue already debugged that out.)

```
//Get file count of user
function getFolderFileCount($uniqueKey){
    $totalCount = 0;
    $directory = "data/storage/uploads/" . $uniqueKey;
    $dirContents = scandir($directory);
    foreach($dirContents as $row){
        if(is_dir($row)){
            $totalCount += getFolderFileCount($directory . "/" . $row);
            $totalCount++;
        }else{
            $totalCount++;
        }
    }
    return $totalCount - 2;
}
```

**The tree of my directory is as follows:**

-www
--access
--code.php    ( <- this is where the code is being ran from)
---data
----storage
-----uploads
------user500493  ( <- this is the $uniqueKey variable and therefore the folder than i need the file count of)

The errors i am getting in my error log is:
https://pastebin.com/g3jGD7u8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the `$directory` variable to the function again instead of the `$uniqueKey '/' $row`.
On the second loop it tries to access `'data/storage/uploads/data/storage/uploads/{$uniqueKey}/{$row}'`.

```
//Get file count of user
function getFolderFileCount($uniqueKey){
    $totalCount = 0;
    $directory = "data/storage/uploads/" . $uniqueKey;

    $dirContents = scandir($directory);
    foreach($dirContents as $row){
        if($row == '.' || $row == '..')
            continue;
        if(is_dir($directory. $row)){
            $totalCount += getFolderFileCount($uniqueKey . "/" . $row);
            $totalCount++;
        }else{
            $totalCount++;
        }
    }
    return $totalCount;
}
```

**Edit:** The code considers subfolders inside the user500493 folder as well.
I did some tests on PHP 7.1.9-1 and it's fully working.
The `is_dir()` parameters must be the path to the folder, not only `$row`because it is only the file or directory name.

Comment: That has deffinatly done somthing, i removed the $directory variable from when i re-call the function but now the console still gets spammed but this time with a scandir() file name too long as it is trying to scan: "data/storage/uploads/user500493/./././././././././././././." infinitely when it should be scanning the sub directory "test"

Comment: Test for $row different than "." and "..", that should do. I would `exit(var_dump($row))` for more insights about understanding what is happening when we scan a dir.

Comment: I have done what you said and that looping error no longer exists. The only thing now is it dosnt actually seem to check the amount of files in the subdirectory.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 2? It was because of "." and ".."? Because since we are ignoring them now you can remove it.

Comment: I have removed the -2 after implementing this. It just does not add the file count of the sub directories now.

Comment: I just edited my answer to a fully working code with includes the subfolders of the user500493 dir.

Comment: I found the issue, when checking if its a directory i don include the actual path of the directory just the $row